# Selected Item Not Appearing Selected in DropDownList for Edit Page

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I am making a basic MVC site for my work and I'm running into an issue with dropdownlists. I have several dropdownlists in my edit view and add view for an educator class but in the edit view they aren't showing the value already selected (stored as Title in the educator class) but are showing the default text "--Please Select--". I want the dropdownlist to be set to the proper item when I go to edit the entry.

I've looked at the local variables while debugging and found that Model.uniqueTitles (the SelectList of educator titles) does contain all of the titles and even has the correct one titled as selected. But when it goes to the view nothing is selected. I have tried switching DropDownListFor to DropDownList and found some interesting results. For DropDownList, if the title string (first input variable) was not spelled correctly, then the drop down would select the correct title, but it could not save it because the title was incorrect so it was saving to nowhere. I am not sure why this happens.

EditEducator View

```
  /* This is not the entire view but it is the only part that is performing differently than expected */

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, (SelectList)Model.uniqueTitles, "-- Please Select --", new {@class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Educator Class

```
public class Educator
{
    public int EducatorID { get; set; } /* Only used when fetching data from Server to edit */
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Educator must have a first name.")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Educator must have a last name.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set;  }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Educator must have an email address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Educator must have a title.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CurrentEmployee { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public SelectList uniqueTitles { get; set; }

    public Educator() { }
```

Educator Controller

```
public ActionResult EditEducator(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var ed = LoadEducator(id); /* Loading requested educator into class instance */
        List<string> stringUniqueTitles = LoadUniqueTitles(); /* Loading all unique titles for educators */ 
        var tmpTitles = stringUniqueTitles.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList(); 
        /* Turning them into List<SelectListItem> */
        var newUniqueSelect = new SelectList(tmpTitles, "Value", "Text", ed[0].Title); 
        /* Turning that into a SelectList with selected value of the title from the fetched educator */

        return View(new Models.Educator
        {
            EducatorID = ed[0].EducatorID,
            FirstName = ed[0].FirstName,
            LastName = ed[0].LastName,
            Email = ed[0].Email,
            Phone = ed[0].Phone,
            Title = ed[0].Title,
            CurrentEmployee = ed[0].CurrentEmployee,
            State = ed[0].State,
            uniqueTitles = newUniqueSelect

        });
    }
```

''''

No error messages are being received, I just have not been able to receive the selected output in the drop down menu.

**EDIT: I found that if I change the primary field of DropDownList (not DropDownListFor) to a different variable "editTitle" and define it in my Educator class then the dropdown selected values work just as they should. However when I submit this I get the following error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure I've found what's wrong with the code. To select a SelectListItem based on its value, the value should be an integer. When I switched the Value to be a unique int the drop down selected the proper value just fine. Feel kind of silly but at least it works now.